# What is the minimum number of sets such that the product of elements in each of them is less than k?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, set-partition, extremal-combinatorics

Given a positive number n and a positive number k. How to find the minimum number of sets such that for each set s , the product of all elements in s is less than or equal to k.

And also all the sets should contain only elements from 1 to n (both inclusive).And each number from 1 to n should be in exactly one set.

My approach was to first find the square root of k (let it be t). And then divide the numbers from 1 to n into 2 parts. First part has numbers less or equal to t , second has numbers greater than t and less than equal to n. Then we can say that no two number in the second part can be in the same set , because their product will be more the k. But this does not completely answer the question. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: The product of all the numbers is $n!$ and so we is we have $s$ sets, we must have $n!\leq k^s$ or $s\geq\left\lceil\frac{\log n!}{\log k}\right\rceil$  So, if we manage to do it with $\left\lceil\frac{\log n!}{\log k}\right\rceil$, we know we've achieved the minimum.  I don't know if this is always possible, nor do I know a good algorithm for constructing the sets.

Comment: A much better way to state the problem would be to ask for the partition of $\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$ such that the product of each element of the partition is less than $k$ and the number of sets in the partition is minimized.

Comment: @saulspatz $(n,k)=(4,5)$ requires $3$ bins, strictly greater than the lower bound of $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this as a [bin packing problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) where the $n$ items have weights $\log 1, \dots, \log n$ and each bin has capacity $\log k$.